# Algorithm for determining reference points

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, face-recognition

Good afternoon.
Please tell me what algorithms define reference points of faces on the picture.  [(example)](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/nui086/facialRecog.jpg)
The only known to me the algorithm to identify persons - Viola-Jones. But it determines only the area in which the faces are located.
The search on the internet as a result - AAM and EBGM. But there is no certainty that these algorithms are suitable and optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AAMs and EBGMs can definitely be used to find feature points on a face. There are also ASM (active shape models), which is where the AAM algorithm came from. CLM is another method (constrained local models).

It depends on what you define as suitable and optimal. AAMs have been used for around 15 years or so, and Active Shape Models go back over 20 years. I have used AAMs extensively in my research, and depending on what you are trying to accomplish they work very well.

[Tim Cootes](http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/timothy.f.cootes/) is the guy who developed these algorithms. He still is active in research with them. His site has a lot of information about this type of material.

[Face Detection, Pose Estimation, and Landmark Localization in the Wild](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~peleg/CVPR2012/data/papers/364_O3B-01.pdf)

Comment: The algorithm will be used to search for people in the group photo (eg from social networks), for the application of image filters.

Comment: These types of "in the wild" images are a difficult problem in image processing. There are research groups that work extensively on them. If you want to find reference points on faces in these types of images you may want to look into using multiple algorithms to help you first detect the face, then find the features you want. I added a new link above for a research paper on this from CVPR, which is the top computer vision conference. I think this is a pretty good paper, I have used it as a reference for my research.